# Java 8 - Difference between reduce(0, Integer::sum) and reduce(0, (a, b) -> a+b)

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, reduce

I am new to `Java 8` and did find some ways to do `addition`, `multiply` and `subtraction`. I will be posting question for add only.

I have written below code and gathering output in Sum1 and Sum2. Both the methods `reduce(0, Integer::sum)` and `.reduce(0, (a, b) -> a+b);` gives the same result. What would be the best method to use performance wise and if using large integer values and why ?

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4);

Integer sum1 = numbers.stream().reduce(0, (a, b) -> a+b);
System.out.println("SUM ="+sum1);

Integer product = numbers.stream().reduce(0, (a, b) -> a*b);
System.out.println("PRODUCT = "+product);

int sum2 = numbers.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);
System.out.println("SUM 2= "+sum2);

Optional<Integer> sum3 = numbers.stream().reduce((a, b) -> (a + b));
System.out.println("SUM3="+sum3);

// Updated as per  @Hadi J comment
int sum4 = numbers.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
System.out.println("Sum ="+sum4);
```

Comment: I think the best method is use `numbers.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();` because `reduce` has multiple autoboxing.

Comment: Oh Ok. I missed to figure out this way :) Any strong reason to use this ? If you can guide further ? UPDATED my statement

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125296/how-to-sum-a-list-of-integers-with-java-streams)

Comment: Cool, Very nice

Comment: the fastest way would be a plain loop, not streams

Comment: There is no difference between `reduce(0, Integer::sum)` and `reduce((a, b) -> a + b)`. For the first, the method `Integer.sum(…)` will be invoked on every evaluation, for the second, a method created within your class will be invoked, which does exactly the same, `return a+b;`. The considerations are similar to [Function.identity() or t->t](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28041480/2711488). While we have no sharing of the generated instance here (yet), calling an existing method reduces code and raises the likelihood of ending up at optimized shared code, but may hinder debugging.

Comment: Worth adding that every line which has `(a, b) -> a + b` is a different lambda making the call to this quickly metamorphic when using `Integer::sum` repeatedly doesn't.

Comment: Another difference is that for `Integer::sum`, the two arguments are `int` type, but for `(a, b) -> a + b` the `a` and `b` are Integer type.  This could result in one being more optimised than the other for some odd reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What would be the best method to use performance wise and if using large integer values and why ?

The main idea is to ignore auto-boxing/unboxing when juggling with primitives and their object representations.

Adding two `Integer` objects is much more sophisticated than adding two `int` primitives. You can find more details in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9391626/10584605).

So the best case is when you have a primitive array `int[]` and sum its elements into an accumulator of type `int`. Thus no boxing involved here.

A worse (but not the worst) case is when you sum an object `Integer` with a primitive `int`. It will cause unboxing of the first argument. 
This is how it works when your initial array or collection contains objects (e.g. Integer[], List, etc...) and the accumulator is primitive. This will cause unboxing of each element of your collection exactly once, while the accumulator will remain the same.

The worst case is summing up a collection of objects into an `Integer` accumulator.

1. Plain old Java:

   - Summing `Integer[]` into `Integer`

     ```
     Integer[] array = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
     Integer sum = 0;
     // Each element of the array will be unboxed exactly once
     // sum will be unboxed 10 times
     // result of the sum will be boxed 10 times
     for(int i : array) sum += i;
     ```
   - Summing `Integer[]` into `int`

     ```
     Integer[] array = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
     int sum = 0;
     // Each element of the array will be unboxed exactly once
     // result of the sum will be boxed 10 times
     for(int i : array) sum += i;
     ```
   - Summing `int[]` into `int`

     ```
     int[] array = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
     int sum = 0;
     // No boxing/unboxing at all
     for(int i : array) sum += i;
     ```
2. Stream API

   - Reducing sum of `Stream<Integer>`

     ```
     Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
     // Each element will be unboxed exactly once
     // The accumulator will be unboxed 10 times
     // The result of the sum operation will be boxed 10 times
     Integer sum = stream.reduce(0, Integer::sum);
     ```
   - Reducing sum of `Stream<Integer>` mapping to primitive `int`

     ```
     Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
     // Each element will be unboxed exactly once
     // Neither accumulator not result will be unboxed/boxed
     int sum = stream.mapToInt(Integer::intValue).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
     ```
   - Reducing sum of `IntStream`

     ```
     IntStream stream = IntStream.of(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
     // No boxing/unboxing at all
     int sum = stream.reduce(0, Integer::sum);
     // same as
     int sum2 = stream.sum();
     ```

Comment: Nice summary! Would be even better if you could provide some jmh benchmarks for the different alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Something interesting:
In Intellij IDEA, when you pass the mouse over the sum() function, there is a ToolTip like this one:

[image]

Returns the sum of the elements in this stream. This is a special case of a reduction and is equivalent to:

```
Public abstract int sum() 
//equal function to
return reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```